# Can I use PHP to add to an RSS feed?

Tags: php

I've created an iPhone application that reads rss items from a feed. I understand this feed can be updated manually simply by adding  tags and adding sufficient info to the RSS file, but I want to do this using an interface. First thing that comes to mind, PHP. I could create an interface with a button that PHP can take the value of a few textboxes when submitted and create the item for me...

I can't seem to find any documentation online for this sort of thing however. Does this mean I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, then again, it won't be fun.

RSS is a subset format of XML, with specific rules. This, in practice, means that you can go two ways about it:

- If you are familiar with `DOMDocument` and its use to parse XML/HTML, I strongly recommend you go down this route. It will allow you to fine-tune your RSS output
- If, on the other hand, you are new to XML parsing and re-encoding overall, you are better off using a library or two to do it.

In terms of libraries, when in a pinch, I personally tend to use the [universal RSS feed generator](http://ajaxray.com/blog/php-universal-feed-generator-supports-rss-10-rss-20-and-atom). Relatively simple to use, handles RSS and ATOM.

If you ARE familiar with `DOMDocument`, here are the things to look out for:

- Before importing your RSS file, you will need to declare the namespaces. This is as easy as adding `setAttributeNS()` with the right definitions and imports
- You will also need to care about the incoming format. Once you've got the hang of how `DOMDocument` works with XML, it is a trivial matter to add nodes. From there, once you're done, just call `DOMDocument->saveXML()` to get your new XML file. Voila, done.

Comment: Great thanks. Looks like the universal RSS feed generator will be the best option for me!